# Flutter - Full text search parse server?

Tags: flutter, parse-platform

I was wondering how I can achieve a full text with the "parse_server_sdk_flutter" pub.
I thought about using `parseQuery.whereContains` but the documentation states that it is case sensitive which would not work for my use case.

Comment: I believe you need to use the `whereContainsWholeWord` function. Could you please give it a try?

Comment: I tried it now but it did not work, since I already built my test I tried `whereContains` and it worked so apparently the documentation is misleading.